# encodeCGSize:forKey: and decodeCGSizeForKey: equivalent for OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm converting a little library to work with Tiled files (tmx extension) for my OS X's sprite kit game. I know there is no possibility to know the source code of the method in UIKit framework, any idea how to substitute these two Cocoa-touch only methods ?

Theses methods are part of the NSCoder class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `encodeSize:forKey` vs `decodeSizeForKey:` in Cocoa ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCoder/encodeSize%3a)).

Example:

```
[myCoder encodeSize:NSSizeFromCGSize(myCGSize) forKey:@"key"];
NSSize mySize = [myDecoder decodeSizeForKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: Shouldn't the decode be: `myCGSize = NSSizeToCGSize([myDecoder decodeSizeForKey:@"key"]);`?